# Not able to resolve DNS at 8.8.8.8, though ping works

Tags: dns

I’m using Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop. I’m not sure how the issue started since it is by no means a fresh install. I’m unable to resolve any DNS hostnames via browser or telnet. I’ve confirmed this on the laptop in question over multiple WiFi networks. I also confirmed that other devices on the same network are not experiencing this issue. I can ping any external IP address (e.g. 8.8.8.8) just fine. I can also visit websites by typing the IP address into the browser.

Things I have tried:

- I tried running [`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/368935) to no effect.
- I’ve also tried going into the [network settings for the WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/a/820873/752924) network and changing the Method to “Automatic (DHCP) addresses only”, then manually adding DNS server addresses.
- I also tried adding a `supersede domain-name-servers` line in my [`etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/887700/752924) which did not resolve the issue either.
- I even manually edited my `/etc/resolv.conf` to replace my nameserver with 8.8.8.8.
- Adding dns-nameservers to `/etc/network/interfaces` file has not helped either.

After each of these experiments failed to enable DNS lookups I restored the original config. I’m not able to install external packages right now such as dnsmasq. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I really am not sure how I got in this mess, but it’s persistent after rebooting as well. I’m not behind a VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by reinstalling my entire operating system. I switched to the LTS line in case the issue was partially caused by some system update.