# block outside dns, fix dns leak ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns, vpn

Using [dns leak test](https://dnsleaktest.com/) while under my VPN I discovered that it was leaking. I've setup my VPN via NetworkManager and it works properly except for the leak.

First, i've tried to add `block-outside-vpn` to the configuration file except that under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` it does not follow the same format. I couldn't find the doc on how to properly write one for dns leaks.

Also, using Ubuntu 18.04 resolv.conf does not work like before, all the other answers are based on that.

Briefly, how to block outside dns (leak) using Network Manager configuration files or the GUI?

Comment: `block-outside-vpn` typically is only a Windows OpenVPN connection option.  Fixing the DNS "leakage" would be to use a specific DNS server that exists only on the other side of the VPN.  What were the DNS Leak Test results you saw?  (they're relevant)

Answer (score 6):

To fix DNS leaks on Ubuntu 18.04, you can edit a file called `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. According to the manual page, this file "provides a means for configuring one or more network interfaces using the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, BOOTP protocol, or if these protocols fail, by statically assigning an address."

As for fixing your DNS leaks, we will be editing this file. Opening it with the proper permissions, you will see a commented line that looks something like this:

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.53;
```

Uncomment this line, and change the domain-name-server to a different one, such as OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222. Using this OpenDNS address, this line would now look like this:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222;
```

After saving the file and rebooting your system, this should fix the DNS leaks on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Or you could just edit your connection in a GUI and get the same result: open edit window for your connection=>IPv4/IPv6 Settings, change "Method" to "Automatic, addresses only" and add yours "DNS servers".

Comment: @GoodGuyNick 's method via the GUI did not work for me. I have googled this problem all day, and only the "prepend domain-name-servers" trick has worked. Hallelujah for this answer. Everything else I tried (including the GUI for DNS servers) was getting overwritten and not surviving reboot.

Comment: no `reboot` needed, but run `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `dnscrypt`.

First install it:

```
sudo apt install dnscrypt-proxy
```

By default it will listens to `127.0.2.1` port `53`.

Edit your VPN or any other connection you like and set `127.0.2.1` as its DNS server, using CLI you can run:

```
nmcli connection modify [CONNECTION-NAME] ipv4.dns 127.0.2.1
```

And just in case block the out going DNS requests:

```
sudo ufw deny out 53
```

And make sure firewall is enabled:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: My DNS is still leaking as per DNS leak test. It's also important to mention that disabling VPN while ufw is enabled would render internet unavailable (blocked port 53).

Comment: Run this command: `nmcli connection modify [CONNECTION-NAME] ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes` see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a DNS leak as indicated by checking on 
[browserleaks.com](https://browserleaks.com/ip) or [dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com),

1. Shut off your VPN connection
2. Attempt to undo any .conf file edits you've wasted time already making.  If you've been trying a lot of various suggestions, your best good chance might be to do a fresh install and ensure you've also installed networkmanager-openvpn-gnome as Ubuntu does not have VPN config importing provided by default.
3. Install dnsmasq

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install dnsmasq
   ```
4. Disable resolved

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
   sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
   ```
5. Remove /`etc/resolv.conf` and create a new one:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
6. Enter into your empty `.conf` file:

   ```
   nameserver 127.0.0.1`         that's all!
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>  to exit the editor. Enter  <kbd>y</kbd> to save and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to overwrite your new `resolv.conf` file.
8. Edit your NetworkManager.conf file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
   ```

   and add the following:

   ```
   dns=dnsmasq
   ```

   beneath the lines (navigate using arrow keys), [main] and plugins=ifupdown, keyfile exactly like this with the new line added.

   ```
   [main]
   plugins=ifupdown, keyfile
   dns=dnsmasq
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the editor. Enter <kbd>y</kbd>  to save and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to overwrite the file.
9. Back out of the terminal, and reboot the system and check your dnsleak test site for results.

With thanks to [Anonymous VPN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYW4aJntC8s) whose solutions for Leaks on Ubuntu/Network Manager seem well researched and successful.  THEY WORK and when no other solutions worked for me, these did.  The above shown solution works for Ubuntu [17.x and 18.04 LTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYW4aJntC8s). See his other solution for [16.04 LTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFbvrIQpeaQ).

Comment: I've tested this solution on a VM and all worked. Then I've tried on a main machine and saw dns from VPN and dns leak. On a VM `nameserver` changed from `127.0.2.1` to `192.168.122.1` and when I connect to VPN in a `resolv.conf` I see two `nameserver` lines, one with `192.168.122.1` and the other with VPNs dns but on a main machine I always see two lines `search lan 
nameserver 127.0.1.1`.

Comment: how can I do what without network manager? just put the dns in /etc/network/interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this exact issue for 2 days before finding the solution that worked for me here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470940

#### TL;DR

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

This is where connections created with the Network Manager are stored.

```
$ sudo nmcli connection modify <vpn-connection-name> ipv4.dns-priority -42
```

Simple command to modify the connection config file. Could be done manually as well but this way I believe is easier.

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Make the changes apply to your system.

*Basically copy pasted from the link above, credit to original author.*

***If your system doesn't know nmcli, or adding connections using the Network Manager GUI throws an error, I recommend [this link](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-use-nmcli-to-connect-to-openvpn-server-on-linux/)***

#### Now for what's less of an explanation and more of a comment (rather clueless myself).

I tried many of the solutions including resolv.conf, dnsmasq and dnscrypt, all of which lead to my internet being blocked either entirely or when the vpn connection was turned off. None of them solved the dns leak, according to [dnsleaktest.com](https://dnsleaktest.com).
If any of these are attempted, each step along the way should be tracked as to be able to reverse them in case of an undesired outcome. It took me no short amount of time to fix my broken internet time and time again without, guess what, internet. I am not claiming that these solutions do not work period, I very possibly made some mistake somewhere. 
***The solution I linked to however has the imho huge advantage that it does not mess with general network settings, but just with the one connection you're modifying.***

Next, block-outside-dns, as mentioned in here before, is a windows only solution and threw some sort of not recognized option error on my ubuntu system.

Using ovpn cli commands did not solve the leak either for me.

The link I provided mentions an explanation ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499523)) about some version inconsistencies that are fixed in ubuntu 18.10, maybe someone with more expertise on this topic cares to explain further. If that's true, LTS users will have to wait for april next year afaik.

Lastly I want to point out that for residents of countries with internet censorship, dns leak poses a heavy issue because allowing the local isp access to your traffic can and will lead to censored domains being blocked despite being connected to a vpn. So for future visits to china etc., this is something you want to take care of beforehand.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `update-systemd-resolved` script that does not make changes to the `resolv.conf`, and instead uses the `systemd-resolved` service using it's DBus API

Get it from git and install it by:

```
git clone https://github.com/aghorler/update-systemd-resolved.git
cd update-systemd-resolved
make
```

Now edit `nsswitch.conf` by:

```
sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

and then change the line starting with `hosts:` to say

```
hosts: files resolve dns myhostname
```

Enable the service and make sure it's running automatically:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
```

---

> **NOTE:** If you don't want to follow the above steps and you're okay with using the terminal, the DNS leak only occurs when using
>   NetworkManager, it so far in my experience does not happen when you
>   run openvpn from the terminal with `sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn`

Comment: What would be the line in config.ovpn that would block the leak? Do you have an example of that? (The solution above did not work for me).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried just about every solution I could find online to fix the dns leak problem. Openvpn started just fine but showed that it was leaking when I went to the test sites.  After I got no joy trying all the remedies, I went into my wifi and ethernet setting and used openvpn's dns servers instead of my ISP's and everything was fine from then on.  I'm sure you've seen the ip addresses all over the place but here they are if you haven't:  208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is

1. Use IP Tables to force everything through your VPN Tunnel
2. Configure you PC to have a static IP Address with DNS server of your choice (DHCP is not your friend)

More detail: https://github.com/OrangeReaper/abStartupManager/wiki/Some-notes-on-Ubuntu-Desktop-Security

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu with a setup from this [repo](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install) for the server part.

And for the client part:

```
apt install update-systemd-resolved
```

In your client .openvpn conf file add these:

```
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
script-security 2
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220
dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```