# How to fix DNS leak of OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

running Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenVPN connected, when I perform a [DNS leak test](https://ipleak.net/), I get a DNS leak: it shows my Internet Service Provider! Same issue with any others DNS leak test site. Please, could you tell me how to fix the DNS leak for OpenVPN or what is the approach to follow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [block outside dns, fix dns leak ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065568/block-outside-dns-fix-dns-leak-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove my default gateway from /etc/resolv.conf after successful VPN connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943008/is-it-possible-to-remove-my-default-gateway-from-etc-resolv-conf-after-successf) (not ideal, but I use it very often, change `ROUTER_IP` variable).

Comment: As a general rule, Ubuntu leaks your location when the Network Manager is used. However, the CLI alternative (`sudo openvpn --config  <ovpn-file>`) usually prevents DNS leaks. Having said that, you should follow the instructions given by your VPN service provider because in some cases, it is necessary to modify the ovpn file to fix this type of issue.