# WiFi DNS problem and shows question mark

Tags: wireless, dns

Now that I've upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04.1 LTS, the WiFi indicator is a question mark, and no longer works.

The only fix I have found that works is for me to manually change my DNS server in `resolv.conf`, but I have to do this every time I restart.

Here is what I do:

[image]

And the result is:

[image]

I then change it:

[image]

And after restarting network-manager, wifi works correctly

> Edit: My problem is not that I want to change my default DNS into a faster one.
>   I would just like wifi to work without me having to manually change my DNS server every time I reboot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Permanently configure the DNS server list in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820667/how-do-i-permanently-configure-the-dns-server-list-in-16-04)

Comment: @guiverc no, his problem about permanently change the normal (working) DNS into the speedy working Google's DNS but my problem is that the normal DNS doesn't work!

Comment: I still think it applies.  However yes you are correct, instead of using DHCP; you follow instructions on the page but instead of Automatic (DHCP; which you want off), you listed DNS servers being the 8.8.8.... you want.  Sorry, I assumed you'd realize this.

Comment: Don't ever set your name server in resolv.conf, head or tail. They'll always be changed on a reboot. That is a temporary change for minor issues and or debugging, always set your name servers in the network manager file because your network manager will overwrite the interfaces file, the dhcp file and the resolv.conf file, dhcp only overwrites the resolv.conf and interfaces overwrites dhcp and interfaces, really dhcp, interfaces and network manager are all great files to choose from, but if it's already pretty set in one. That might be the core of your ::: problem

Comment: Also, if you want to restart your interfaces at the same time you restart your network manager, change false to true in the network manager file, then restart network manager

Comment: Google DNS is faster even though you aren't looking for a faster solution, faster, secure and bugged :) while your ISP's nameserver probably doesn't alarm, speed up anything, they just provide the service and block/filter sites like Ubuntu if it's certificate isn't up to date or authentic I guess you could say